# Does some tables in Informix take values of a column only in lower case?

Tags: database, informix

I find some columns in tables such as **name** column in  **sysdbspaces** table of **sysmaster** database and likewise some columns in tables in Informix take only lower case letters . Suppose I create a dbspace with name **SAmple** using `onspaces` command  the new value in **name** column of **sysdbspaces** would be **sample** and not **SAmple** and if I query for dbspace whose name = 'SAmple' it is returning null . how to deal with case sensitivity in this type of cases ?

Comment: You can get upper-case (or mixed-case) user names into the system if you want to by enclosing the name in quotes.  With sysdbspaces, I think you're stuck; the names are converted to lower-case, period.  Don't use mixed case searches on columns that only contain lower-case values.

Comment: may I know Mr.Leffler , what are the tables like **sysdbspaces** in which column values are converted into lower case ? I found the same case with **username** column in **sysusermap** table of **sysuser** database , can I create a username with mixed case like **McDonald** ?

Comment: `CREATE TABLE 'McDonald'.Ronald(t INTEGER NOT NULL)` works and uses the name `McDonald` in the `owner` column.  You can also play with delimited identifiers (names delimited by double quotes), but you need to set the DELIMIDENT env var.

Comment: Sir , If  your comment itself is the answer please put that in answer section so that I can mark it as correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sup>*Transferring comments into an answer.*</sup>

You can get upper-case (or mixed-case) user names into the system if you want to by enclosing the name in quotes. With sysdbspaces, I think you're stuck; the names are converted to lower-case, period. Don't use mixed case searches on columns that only contain lower-case values.

As an example of mixed-case names in the system catalogue:

```
 CREATE TABLE 'McDonald'.Ronald(t INTEGER NOT NULL)
```

works and uses the name `McDonald` in the owner column. You can also play with delimited identifiers (names delimited by double quotes), but you need to set the DELIMIDENT environment variable.

Incidentally, in a MODE ANSI database, you might write:

```
create table whodunnit.murder_mystery (t integer not null);
```

and the system catalog will record the owner as WHODUNNIT in caps.  Unless you quote the user name, or the user name is `informix`, it will be case-converted.